# Reverting in subversion

Tags: svn, revert

Say I want to revert some changes between version n and (n-1) in Subversion.

I would just put back the files from version (n-1) - take them from the repository and check back in as the latest version in the trunk.

Here it seems they want to make a branch from version (n-1) and merge it back with the trunk.

How is this better or "more correct"?

In this case it is a few files within one directory.
These files do not have other recent changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove changes between specific revisions, say 1000 and 1010 in the past:

From a checked out, up to data working copy type:

```
svn merge -r 1010:1000 .
```

This removes all the changes in your working copy between revisions 1000 and 1010 (not including changes added to 1000 itself). It's safe to play around with this as long as you don't have any local modifications and don't check the results back in until you've verified that it did what you wanted.

In your particular case since you only want to remove a single revision you can use '-c' instead of the more general -r:

```
svn merge -c 2000 .
```

This is equivalent to -r 1999:2000 removing the changes between 1999 and 2000.

Comment: It doesn't directly answer my question (I guess its what they are doing in my company), but it make me think it is the better way.

I assume this would work on a part of the directory three?

Comment: What if I would like to keep the changes in a branch (move them to a branch)?

Comment: You can create a branch from any revision including one with the changes. You can also run merge commands on the branch to move specified changes onto or off of the branch.

Answer (score 2):

**To cleanly remove a bad commit for you and for others...**

the "revert" is not the one you are looking for, because it only affects local changes. in order to revert a already submitted revision you have to use "svn merge" using the negate syntax by putting a "-" (minu) in front of the revision you wish to remove.example:

```
current rev: 1337

bad rev: 1330

$sh> svn merge -c -1330 svn://your.svn.url:/your.svn.path .
$sh> svn ci -m "removed revision 1330"
```

so you do reverse-merge your repository with rev "-1330" and do a checkin afterwards thus removing the changes from 1330 for you and the other developers.

Will

Answer (score 0):

Use `svn merge`, it's very useful for your scenario.

```
svn merge -c n http://xxxx/xxx/xx
```